# Thread safety with map and concurrentHashMap

Tags: java, multithreading

Below are two approaches, both creating instance of concurrentHashMap, my understanding is that approach 2 is thread safe but not approach 1. But am having conversation with colleague and per him, since both are creating instance of concurrentHashMap should not approach 1 be also thread safe also?

Approach 1:

```
private static final Map<key, value> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<key, value>();
```

Approach 2:

```
private static final ConcurrentHashMap<key, value> concurrentHashMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<key, value>();
```

Would appreciate any clarifications on this.

Comment: That's basically the same difference as between saying "here's my son, John", and "here's my child, John". Whatever the way you refer to John, iy's always John. That's basic polymrphism, and you should definitely understand that before even thinking about multithreading and thread-safety, which are much more complex matters.

Comment: You can also use `Collections.synchronizedMap(map)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are creating a `ConcurrentHashMap` in both cases, so the thread safety is exactly the same.

`ConcurrentHashMap` implements the `Map` interface, which is what you're calling through in example 1.  But this has no impact on the underlying object that was instantiated.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly the object has the same runtime type in both cases.

However, when viewed as a `Map` the `putIfAbsent` and other `ConcurrentMap` methods are hidden from clients.  Denying them this and forcing them to use the traditional `put` and `get` is the concern I expect your colleague is voicing.

Answer (score 1):

Both solutions are thread safe. You should get more familiar with java interfaces:) 
Because both are references to same map implementation. First solution hides that fact through an interface, second doesn't.
First approach is even claner- its recommend to use api interface instead of class obj, when it comes to collections. This will help to apply changes to your code.
I hope my explanation helps a bit.

Answer (score 0):

The following only creates a pointer for Map object and instantiates it to null.

```
private static final Map<key, value> map;
```

The following line it's where the object is really created, in both cases is an instance of **ConcurrentHashMap**, and the variable map points to it's address. **This is what matters, the actual instance.**

```
map = new ConcurrentHashMap<key, value>();
```

**So there cannot be any difference between the two!**